# Excel VBA -- Edit 1,000,000 rows CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to clean up CSV data to correct the Fisrt Name and Last Name format.
It works fine on my PC machine (it takes ~20sec to complete) and all data is likely processed well.
But my friends tell me that it's not working on her machine, it takes only 4sec and stop. Not all of the data processed.

What's wrong with below code?
Thanks

```
Sub CleanUpCSV()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim sCSV As TextStream, oCSV As TextStream
Dim sFile As String, oFile As String, sFileName As String, oFileName As String
Dim ln As String
Dim varData As Variant, varName As Variant
Dim CName As Long, FName As Long, LName As Long
Dim sFilePath As String, sFolderPath As String
Dim FilterIndex As Integer
Dim filter As String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim lfn As Long, lln As Long, lcn As Long


FastWB True
'open the Sage CSV file
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
   ' .InitialFileName = local_path
    .Title = "Please select csv file to be cleaned up"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        sFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        sFile = sFilePath
    End If
End With

If Len(sFilePath) > 0 Then
    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    sFileName = fso.GetFileName(sFile)
    sFolderPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(sFile)

    oFileName = "Cleaned_" & sFileName
    oFile = sFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & oFileName

    CName = 3 'Complete Name, 4th Column
    FName = 4 'First Name, 5th Column
    LName = 5 'Last Name, 6th Column

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sCSV = fso.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading, False)
    Set oCSV = fso.CreateTextFile(oFile, True)
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Do While Not sCSV.AtEndOfStream
        ln = sCSV.ReadLine
        varData = Split(ln, ",")
        lfn = UBound(Split(CStr(varData(FName)), " "))
        lln = UBound(Split(CStr(varData(LName)), " "))

        If Not LCase(CStr(varData(CName))) Like "*name" Then 'ignore 1st line
            If lfn < 1 And lln > 0 Then
                varName = Split(CStr(varData(LName)), " ")
                If UBound(varName) > LBound(varName) Then
                    varData(FName) = varName(UBound(varName))
                    varData(LName) = varName(LBound(varName))
                    varData(CName) = varData(FName) & " " & varData(LName)
                End If
            End If

            If lfn > 0 And lln < 1 Then
                varName = Split(CStr(varData(FName)), " ")
                If UBound(varName) > LBound(varName) Then
                    varData(FName) = varName(UBound(varName))
                    varData(LName) = varName(LBound(varName))
                    varData(CName) = varData(FName) & " " & varData(LName)
                End If
            End If

            If lfn > -1 And lln > -1 Then
                varData(CName) = varData(FName) & " " & varData(LName)
            End If
        End If
        ln = Join(varData, ",")
        oCSV.WriteLine ln
    Loop

    sCSV.Close
    oCSV.Close
    Set sCSV = Nothing
    Set oCSV = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    MsgBox "Clean up completed in " & SecondsElapsed & "seconds." & vbCrLf & _
            "Pls check: " & oFileName, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Call OpenFolder(sFolderPath)
Else
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical

End If

ExitSub:
'clean up before exiting
FastWB False
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox "Error", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:excel] or [tag:excel-vba]? You are opening a csv text file, processing it in-memory then writing back to a text file.

Comment: Is your friend using a Mac?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, it's create another CSV file as the output of the process.

Comment: @TimWilliams My friend use windows 10, Excel 2016

Comment: Is your friend using 64-bit Excel?

Comment: Yes, my friend use 64-bit Excel. 
I use Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, and Excel 2010 64 bit. Is there something need to do with that??

Comment: Does your friend not see any errors when it runs?

Comment: No,
it just run and stop without error but the data is not processed properly.
We use the same sample file but different result.

Comment: It's difficult to offer any suggestions without more information - how far does the script get and at what point does it fail (you can track using breakpoints or `Debug.Print` statements for example) and why is there no error message...